# Amazon Polly `builder.continueOnSuccessWith` in iOS not responding

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I want to integrate the AWS polly service to my iOS application for text to speech purpose. I have setup the code that is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/main/Polly-Sample/Swift) as starter project. I have setup the `CognitoIdentityPoolId` in AWS console correctly.

This is the code that is use for getting the URL of inputed text but
the closure `builder.continueOnSuccessWith` that is responsible for getting url is not running or giving any error.

```
let input = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilderRequest()

        // Text to synthesize
        input.text = "Sample text"

        // We expect the output in MP3 format
        input.outputFormat = AWSPollyOutputFormat.mp3

        // Choose the voice ID
        input.voiceId = AWSPollyVoiceId.joanna

        // Create an task to synthesize speech using the given synthesis input
        let builder = AWSPollySynthesizeSpeechURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(input)

        // Request the URL for synthesis result
        builder.continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (awsTask: AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
            // The result of getPresignedURL task is NSURL.
            // Again, we ignore the errors in the example.
            let url = awsTask.result!

            // Try playing the data using the system AVAudioPlayer
            self.audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL))
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            debugPrint("Player success")
            return nil
        })
```

I am not getting any error in console as well. How to debug where is the issue ??